# Select and Enter the largest order values below: How to do that in Selenium Webdriver using Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Steps: Select and Enter the largest order values below (this largest values change the location & Values every time). See the image for more understanding. 
https://challengers.flood.io/start

[image]

Comment: You need to be more specific and through in presenting your questions. Also it would be useful if you can post the HTML.

Answer (score 3):

- Walk through all the child's of the list of bullets, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28045084/1088584) for an idea how todo this in Java.
- Save their values in a temporary array/list
- Use [a MAX function](http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2013/08/largest-or-maximum-value-in-array-java-calculate-find.html) to find the highest score in the array/list.

After you have the highest score you can find the bullet you want to click.

We cannot give you a code example without the HTML of the page and or knowing which programming language you are using for Selenium.

Comment: If it is C# they can use LINQ as well to iterate through a list of Elements using max and just click that one.

Answer (score 0):

First: have to figure it out Max value then have to select the radio button then have to type max value into text box, hope you understate guys!! If you don't know how to do it, please don't assume it..I know everybody expert in here... please help me with the solution?

I tried with this bellow code:

```
WebElement NUMBER1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='new_challenger']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div/span/label"));  
WebElement NUMBER2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='new_challenger']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/div/span/label"));
WebElement NUMBER3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='new_challenger']/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/div/span/label"));
WebElement NUMBER4 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='new_challenger']/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/div/span/label"));
WebElement NUMBER5 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='new_challenger']/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/div/span/label"));

String [] Value = {NUMBER1.getText(), NUMBER2.getText(), NUMBER3.getText(),     NUMBER4.getText(), NUMBER5.getText()};
for(int i=0; i<Value.length; i++){
System.out.println(Value[i]);
                }

List b = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toString(Value));
System.out.println(Collections.max(b));
```

But it doesn't give me the max value.

Answer (score -2):

```
WebElement textBox = driver.findElement(By.id("challenger_largest_order"));
    List<WebElement> redioButtonlist = driver.findElements(By.className("collection_radio_buttons"));
    System.out.println("Total Number of Index is " + redioButtonlist.size());
    int maxNumber = 0;
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= redioButtonlist.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= redioButtonlist.size(); j++) {

            if (maxNumber <= Integer.valueOf(redioButtonlist.get(i).getText())) {
                maxNumber = Integer.valueOf(redioButtonlist.get(i).getText());
            }
            if (maxNumber == Integer.valueOf(redioButtonlist.get(i).getText())) {
                index = i;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(String.valueOf("The MaximumNumber is " + maxNumber));
    textBox.sendKeys(String.valueOf(maxNumber));
    redioButtonlist.get(index).click();
```

** this should be work 
for select Maximum number(used Index) and write in Text box (used maxNumber) .

Comment: Welcome to SQA stack exchange. We prefer to see answers with explanations rather than just code. Could you please edit your answer to explain how it solves the OP's problem?